# How to use JSON file with Cluster Force

Tags: json, d3.js

I wish to use Cluster Force Layout as described by Mike here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658

The example works fine for me, however, the problem is when I change the data source to a JSON file, which uses a different cluster name, things stop working. No errors, but does not display.

The goal is to group the names in each division into a cluster.

The JSON file is in the html... not sure if you can upload data for jsfiddle

Any direction here much appreciated.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xbme6ekf/

This is where I try to recreate the nodes. The nodes appear in console.log, but never make it to the screen.

```
var nodes = d3.json("/r.json", function(error, data) {

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    for (var key in obj){
        var rating = obj['rating']; // rating
        var r = rating * 20;        // radius
        var n = obj['name'];        // name
        var div = obj['division'];  // division
        // d = {cluster: div, radius: r, name: n, division: div, rating: rating};
        d = {cluster: div, radius: r};
        // console.log(key+"="+obj[key]);
    } 
    if (!clusters[i] || (r > clusters[i].radius)) clusters[i] = d;
    // console.log(d);
}
return d;
});
```

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: First of all, the second argument in d3.json is a callback, not an accessor. Second, d3.json returns a d3.xhr object, not data. Third, this is an asynchronous request so the data must be consumed by the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) to add json file if you want to play with extra data file.
Second, I copied your code from fiddle to plunkr with json file, the `console.log(nodes)` didn't print out the data, it's because the code retrieving data here:

```
var nodes = d3.json("/r.json", function(error, data) {...})
```

is not exactly the same as in the example, because this is asynchronous request, so this line of code won't work:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
.nodes(nodes) // data for nodes is not retrieved yet
```

Third, after I put d3 code into the request callback, there is circles in svg but not visible, I think it is because of the svg size setting (width, height) is not quite fit for the `cx`, `cy` of the circles, so I changed the svg to a smaller size, and it's visible. It depends on what you want to achieve at the end, but adjusting the position parameter for the circles can be helpful.

Working plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yw1mpdZDcn0MvNC68j6M?p=preview). Hope this can help.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: A side affect seems to be that the clusters, when broken, do not cluster back together again.

Comment: @KevinWaterson does broken mean you drag away the circles?

Comment: Yes, when a circle is dragged, it does not re-cluster, nor do the other circles in the same group follow a circle when dragged, as in the demo.